# Is it advisable to use LinearLayout inside ConstraintLayout in Android?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am new to `ConstraintLayout` in Android and newbie to Android too. I have a question. Is it advisable to use `LinearLayout` inside `ConstraintLayout`? For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/landing_screen"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.braigolabs.braigo.landing.LandingActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/landing_screen"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="51dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="66dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="66dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/login_welcome_braigolabs"                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="93dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="403dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:text="@string/login_login_button_title"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="116dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="543dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also curious to know how popular is the `ConstraintLayout` among the developers?

Comment: I think at least with AppCompatTextView it renders noticeably faster if the views are wrapped in a linear layout .. it is more noticeable with large number of views

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> Is it advisable to use LinearLayout inside ConstraintLayout?

No... usually.

In general, the idea behind `ConstraintLayout` is that it allows you to position all of your children without having to nest any other `ViewGroup`s inside the `ConstraintLayout`. As such, I would say that it is not *advisable*.

However, there *are* some things that a `LinearLayout` can do that a `ConstraintLayout` can't (mostly revolving around weighted spacing of views), and so if you need these particular corner cases in your layout, you won't have any option other than falling back to a `LinearLayout`.

> how popular is the ConstraintLayout among the developers?

`ConstraintLayout` is relatively new, but it is quite powerful and certainly something that you ought to familiarize yourself with. It won't always be the perfect tool for the job at hand, but it will often allow you to easily create layouts you would otherwise spend hours on.

I can't speak to widespread adoption statistics, but I can say that I've seen tons of questions on this site about the correct usage of `ConstraintLayout`, so clearly devs around the world are starting to work with it.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @Ben. Why someone put a downvote? This is a fairly relevant question.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I believe that your question is, broadly speaking, asking for _opinion_ rather than presenting a specific programming issue. This is generally considered off-topic.

Comment: Can we have nested ConstraintLayout's?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky sure. Again, nesting constraintlayouts is somewhat defeating the idea of using constraintlayout to achieve a totally flat view hierarchy. But there will certainly be cases where nesting views makes your code more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 13):

As of the `2.0.0-alpha5` release of the `constraintlayout` library, it's now possible to declare a [Flow](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow) virtual layout element within your [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout) which (as the name suggests) determines how referenced items are to flow (e.g. vertically, horizontally) within the [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout). So it's no longer necessary to declare a [LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout) within your [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout).

For example, if you wanted items within your [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout) to flow vertically, you'd do so like this:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I am the first TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I am the second TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I am the third TextView" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView1,textView2,textView3"
        app:flow_horizontalAlign="start"
        app:flow_verticalGap="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can play around with the `app:flow_` attributes in the [Flow](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow) element to achieve different flow behaviour. For more information about the [Flow](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow) element, refer to the release notes [here](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/04/constraintlayout-200-alpha-5.html). For an example, see [here](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/ConstraintLayoutExperiments/tree/master/app1).