# how can I put empty space between password and register button in my constrainlayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, spacing

I am developing android app and I have implemented constrainlayout but in real device password edit text and register button overlapping to each other I want to empty space between them how can achieve that

below my currentlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_back"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/person_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/firstname"
        style="@style/textFieldStyle"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        style="@style/textFieldStyle"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lastName"
        tools:ignore="TextFields" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/registration"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/gray"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_black"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="@string/register"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/already_have_account"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/password"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/already_have_account"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:text="@string/already_have_an_account"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryBlack"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.33"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:text="@string/login"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.73"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        style="@style/textFieldStyle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/email"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/email"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lastName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        style="@style/textFieldStyle"
        android:hint="@string/lastName"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

following  screenshot in real device [image: screenshot in real device] I want to know what I have to do in order to put  space between password and register button

but I want to see in real device as if you see there space between password and  register button [image: ui I want to see]

Answer (score 1):

Add a constraint from the top of the register button to the bottom of the password field. Every element should have a top and bottom constraint to not overlap another element that is above or below it.

Comment: you suggestion did not help can you explain wit coding sample

Comment: I'm on mobile right now so it's quite hard to give you a code example so I can give you one tomorrow if you want, but you should be able to give your register button constraints like you gave your EditText's constraints.

Comment: this my button constrains can you check it app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/already_have_account"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/password"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/password"

Comment: Consider editing your answer by adding the XML code or proper steps (if done only by dragging widgets).

Comment: @yes I have tried as many people told but still overlapping

Comment: Your constraint 'app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/password' is the one you need to make sure it keeps at the same distance in comparison to the password field, but if the constraint isn't applied it might be because it doesn't have a lot of space to be inbetween the password field and 'already have an account' field. Try to move everything up.

Answer (score 1):

When you do something like `android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"`, you will eventually get some views overlapping and that's because you are using hardcoded values, you want to adjust your views to the size of your screen in a responsive way.

You can do it using [Guidelines](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Guideline), `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.xx"` and chain verticly your views:

Inside you constarintLayout (I have used a single layout)

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.25"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.07"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="FirstName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.07"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="LastName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.07"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Email"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.07"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Password"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.07"
        android:text="Register"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName4" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.85" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Already have account?"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Log in"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
```

It will look like this (arrows pointing to the guidelines):

[image]

Comment: if you look my view I only want white space between password edittext and signing button I have my design in figma I have to follow this but thank you for your answer

Comment: Because of  `android:layout_height="100dp"` on smaller devices it is pushing down your entire layout and your buttons are getting no space.You can try to give you image responsive size for example `   android:layout_height="0dp"`  with `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"`' this is just an example feel free to play with it for your needs

Answer (score 0):

Adding `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf`.

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/registration"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/gray"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_black"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="@string/register"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/already_have_account"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/password"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/password" />
```

Adding `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/registration"`

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    style="@style/textFieldStyle"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/email"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/email"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/registration" />
```

The above solution works only when all of your views are within a single screen. If height of the View is bigger than the screen, then you may need `ScrollView` or other method.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white">

            ... your main content here ...

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Adding `ScrollView` and `LinearLayout` outside your main content `ConstraintLayout` solves the overlapping issue, and allow bigger view to scroll on smaller view.

Comment: yes but now email and password is overlapping

Comment: Adding outer layer of `ScrollView` and `LinearLayout` solve the bigger view on smaller screen.

Comment: it is not recommended adding constrainlayout inside constrainlayout

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45625844/is-it-advisable-to-use-linearlayout-inside-constraintlayout-in-android/45626000

Comment: The suggested answer is to place `ConstraintLayout` inside `LinearLayout` to solve the bigger view on smaller screen. The discussion is [the other way round](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45625844/is-it-advisable-to-use-linearlayout-inside-constraintlayout-in-android/45626000).

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the margin_botton of the password field and also decreasing margin_botton of the Button.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that your register button is bottom aligned, while the above elements are top aligned, which means they will overlap on smaller screens.

Try updating your Register button in the following way to enforce a minimum top margin with the password field if there is too little space (I just added a constraint to the password field, set constraintVerticalbias to 1.0 and set a topMargin):

```
     <Button
            android:id="@+id/registration"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="ENTER YOUR TOP MARGIN HERE"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/gray"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_black"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="@string/register"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/already_have_account"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/password"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
```

**IMPORTANT: To make this work you need to wrap your screen in a Scrollview with     android:fillViewport="true".**

Here would be your whole layout reworked so that it should work (with registerbutton minimum top margin of 40dp):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_back"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/person_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            style="@style/textFieldStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:hint="@string/firstname"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            style="@style/textFieldStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/name"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lastName"
            tools:ignore="TextFields" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/registration"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/gray"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_black"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="@string/register"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/already_have_account"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/password"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/already_have_account"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:text="@string/already_have_an_account"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryBlack"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.33"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:text="@string/login"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.73"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            style="@style/textFieldStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/email"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/email"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lastName"
            style="@style/textFieldStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/lastName"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/name"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```